# Show destarring in chat message history

Tags: feature-request, chat

Moderators and room owners have the ability to remove stars from chat messages. Currently this leaves no trace on the chat message that it was ever starred or who destarred it. Compare that to pinned messages, where you can see in the chat message history who pinned it.

Destarring a post is not a normal user action, but a moderation action and should in my opinion be logged in the message history.

This is not an important issue, if it's easy to add it would be nice to have it, but it's not an essential feature by any means.

Comment: I agree, this has had some problems [in the Python room](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189325/stars-mysteriously-disappearing-in-the-python-chat-room?lq=1)

Comment: More than just a log of the history of who starred or un-starred messages, I think that the list of users who starred a message should be made available as well.

Comment: We are not going to implement this now.  We're working on the site re-designs and are focused on those at the moment.  This is something we can reconsider in the future.