# Stars mysteriously disappearing in the Python Chat Room

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

A few weeks ago, in the [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python), a few of the room owners got together and decided that the starred list was getting a bit out of hand (from memory about 100-150 messages, maybe even more). We cleaned up several of the useless messages that were in the list (a shame we [can't cancel stars from the transcript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166376/allow-cancelling-of-stars-from-message)). The list was reduced to maybe 80 messages, but we couldn't really delete any more.

Then, during the course of a few weeks, the starred list progressively got smaller in bursts at a time. I had thought it was just some room owners dutifully cleaning the list. But just today,  I noticed the list was reduced from about 40 to only 8 messages. The three most active room owners claim not to have touched the list, and the others are just rarely active, or we reasoned that they wouldn't bother with it.

See from [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/10677116#10677116) to view the brief conversation we had.

---

The question is, did some moderator happen to pop in and clean up the list? Was it some other, mysterious power? Or was it just poor reasoning on our part?

Comment: On a side note, but possibly related. There were some messages that had not only been starred but also "Pinned" However, I noticed recently that they were no longer "Pinned" and When I tried to I got this message: "You have already voted, but the voting has been cleared by a moderator"

Comment: You've _got_ to see what the logical conclusion here is. What you say point to a very clear fact. I hope for you and your room I turn out wrong :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum are you suggesting that the room owners all have poor reasoning and aren't good room owners? ;)

Comment: There's no way to determine who destarred a message (at least for mods), I've [a feature request to change that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122305/show-destarring-in-chat-message-history), but that isn't implemented. But my guess would be that it was a room owner, SO mods are far too busy to go around removing chat stars.

Comment: Don't worry, Donna and the Doctor will sort this out.